# AngularJS Example Not Working

Tags: angularjs, html

I am new to AngularJS so I've been doing some tutorials and following some sample videos.  I came across a very simple application but I cannot get it to run in my browser.  Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="hello"> 
<head lang="en"> 
    <title>My HTML 5 Page</title> 
</head> 
<body>

<h1>{{hello}}</h1> 
<input type="text" ng-model="hello" />

<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js" />

</body>

</html>
```

Do I have to run this from a webserver? Can I not run this in just the browser?  I've tried both ways and neither way worked for me.  I just end up with a big {{hello}} -

> ## {{hello}}

and there's no text input box and definitely no binding. Do I need all the other dependencies?  Shouldn't the script tag line contain everything I need?

I do not have any modules or anything else.  Just an HTML file with those lines of code.

Thanks for any insight you gurus might shed on this mystery.

Comment: what does your javascript look like?

Comment: dbarnes: The only javascript I've included is the angular.min.js library provided from angularjs.org.

Comment: Voting to close. [From the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437151/angularjs-example-not-working#comment47043391_29437225): "*Turns out I cannot self close a script tag.*"

Comment: You probably would want to throw the app.js in there, at least.

Comment: How do I close?  And why the down vote?!  It's a legitimate question from a newbie who was banging her head against this hello-world example for two days and finally got pointed in the right direction by "Explosion Pills" even though the final answer was slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your console for errors which will probably tell you something like the module `hello` is not defined.

The above will only work if you have a script that runs `angular.module("hello", [])` or if you simply remove `hello` and just use `ng-app` with no argument.

Comment: I have removed the "hello" from the code and it still doesn't work. However, thank you for the tips about the console.  I forgot to turn that out.  Turns out I cannot self close a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was 2 things...

1. I needed to remove the "hello" from ng-app
2. I cannot self-close a script tag.  Finally code that worked:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> 
> <html ng-app>
> <head lang="en"> 
>     <title>My HTML 5 Page</title> 
> </head> 
> <body>
>
> <h1>{{hello}}</h1> 
> <input type="text" ng-model="hello" />
>
> <script type="text/javascript" 
>         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js">
> </script>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="page"> 
<head lang="en"> 
    <title>My HTML 5 Page</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<div ng-controller="PageController as page" >
    <h1>{{page.product.message}}</h1> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="hello" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>


code for app.js 

<html ng-app="page"> 
<head lang="en"> 
    <title>My HTML 5 Page</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<div ng-controller="PageController as page" >
    <h1>{{page.product.message}}</h1> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="hello" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app1.js"></script>
</html>
```